# lightning component CSP is preventing me from use inline base64 data for audio tags

Tags: salesforce, content-security-policy, salesforce-lightning

how should I reproduce audio encoded in base64 within a lightning component?
at the moment I get this error message :

Refused to load media from 'data:audio/ogg;base64, ' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src 'self' *.na53.visual.force.com https://.na53.content.force.com".

The media resource is retrieved on the fly that way I can not have a static url which can be config as CSP Trusted Site.

Comment: Change the CSP policy (header?) to have `data:` in it: `media-src 'self' data: *.na53.visual.force.com https://.na53.content.force.com`

Comment: yes, that is one way to go but first I need to generate an object url from a blob (that fine, I can do it). Lets say that I use URL.createObjectURL(obj), the result of that is something like this 'blob:<URL>/d1fe40cc-9f0....-9f0-d1fe40cc'. Now lets try to get the <URL>(this url will be something like <domain>.lightning.force.com) portion of the string and use it as CSP Trusted Sites. At this point when refresh the lightning component I still see the js error with a difference: media-src 'self' <domain>.lightning.force.com *.na53.visual.force.com https://.na53.content.force.com. Next .....

Comment: ..... Continue. Even though now I can see my extracted <URL> as part of the CSP I am still not able to make it work, same message as before : 'Refused to load media from....'

Comment: I am facing similar issue when trying to display video on my lightning component. The video src is data:video/mp4;base64, <Encodedbase64Data> Any solution to this?